# How can I enter the safe (recovery) mode in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, safe-mode

After replacing a GPU Windows won't boot. After the initial logo it's stuck at a blank screen. Attempting to use <kbd>F8</kbd> to enter the safe/recovery mode failed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-enter-safe-mode-in-windows-10/#w1:

> 1. Ensure your computer is off.
> 2. Press the power button to turn on your PC, and when you see the small spinning circle of dots that indicates Windows is starting, press and hold the power button until your PC shuts down. You’ll have to hold it for 4-5 seconds.
> 3. Do this again, and then again. After you’ve done it 3 times, start your computer again and let it run. It should now go into Automatic Repair mode.

The menu that appears than allows booting into various Safe mode alternatives.

---

The post also explains how to enable using <kbd>F8</kbd> to enter the safe mode. Run the following command with administrator privileges:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

Comment: You can also just use Settings to boot to Advanced Startup.